# Selenium Python unable to find web element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have been trying to extract posts from a forum found at this URL: https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=7263973

The body of the text I am trying to extract is under:

```
<div class="post-content">
```

Yet I keep getting the following error whether I use get element to search by XPATH or CLASS_NAME:

```
NoSuchElementException
```

I have tried the following as well as looking at several of the similar posts on SO but can't find a solution that works for me, any help would be appreciated

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.headless = True

def get_posts(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options) 
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    driver.get(url)                                                                            
#   posts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]').text 
    posts = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'post-content');
    return posts

SR_posts = get_posts(url = "https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=7263973")
SR_posts
```

Edit: added picture to the HTML class 'post-content' that contains the text
[HTML of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2VwF.png)

Edit 2: Second picture of inspect element
[Inspect element of text body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEu7S.png)

Comment: If I open that webpage there is no `post-content` into any class. Well, there is no `post-content` anywhere

Comment: Hi @JakyRuby I have added a screenshot of the inspect element to hopefully show what I mean

Comment: Maybe the element isn't immediately available. Use selenium to wait for its visibility

Comment: I also could not find element with class name `post-content` on that page. Not even after scrolling the page down

Comment: @Prophet On the second picture I've included I inspected element on the text and that brought me to the div class="post-content"

Comment: @Kusanagi  saw your picture. But I also opened the link itself. And there was no such element there

Comment: @Kusanagi there is no such element in the link you shared, please, open the link you posted in your question and try to search for `post-content` in your dev tool and you will see it does not exist. Maybe you have to be logged in or something? Or the page changes because you have to do something else before?

Comment: @Prophet, @Jaky Ruby If it is possible would you be able to test if this returns anything for you in the dev tool? ```div class="styles_PostContent-sc-1r7c0ap-3 kylDhV"``` I am wondering if the issue is to do with the fact I am on a Mac M1 and the above class is what appears in the HTML when I switch to my Windows machine

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't see such element there

Comment: Okay, thanks for checking that for me

Comment: What if you try with: `posts = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'styles__PostContent-sc-1r7c0ap-3 kylDhV');`? Does it work?

Comment: @JakyRuby it doesn't throw the error anymore, instead it just doesn't return me anything

Comment: @Kusanagi okay you have an answer with a fully working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the value of the post:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver


def get_posts(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    driver.get(url)
    post = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='styles__PostContent-sc-1r7c0ap-3 kylDhV']/span")))
    return post

SR_post = get_posts(url = "https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=7263973")
print(SR_post.text)
```

Advices:

- Wait always for the element you want to interact for
- Use EC (Expected conditions) to verify your element is accessible in the way you need (In my example is `EC.presence_of_element_located` but you could want something else like wait to be clickable etc.

I used those 2 advices in the code.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much for your help. If it's not too much trouble, is it possible to return all of the posts on that forum link? Currently the code is just returning the first post

Comment: You are asking for the replys, not the post. And that is a totally different topic. Now you can get the post text, from now you have to investiigate how to get the replies, with the code of my answer you should be able to continue